# How to Stop stream of image when we use yield in python

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, yield

I use q to stop it but it does not work while streaming of video in opencv. below is the complete code: cv2 is already imported

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

while True:
        return_value, frame = vid.read()
        if return_value:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        else:
            print('Video has ended or failed, try a different video format!')
            break
        fps = 1.0 / (time.time() - start_time)
        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS: " + str(round(fps, 2)), (10, 50), font, 3, (255, 0, 0), 3)
        result = np.asarray(frame)
        result = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        if output:
            out.write(result)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

        _, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        time.sleep(.01)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + jpeg.tobytes() + b'\r\n\r\n')
```

Give some solution how can we stop streaming?

Comment: There is not enough information here to go on. What is the whole code? the `yield` means the function is a generator. How is it being looped over?

Comment: It works on while loop

Comment: '''while True:
        return_value, frame = vid.read()
        if return_value:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        else:
            print('Video has ended or failed, try a different video format!')
            break
        fps = 1.0 / (time.time() - start_time)
        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS: " + str(round(fps, 2)), (10, 50), font, 3, (255, 0, 0), 3)
        result = np.asarray(frame)
        result = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)'''

Comment: you need to decide, *who, when and why*  should stop the stream

Comment: If that's really the complete code then you're misusing yield.  It should only be used within a function.  But then if that is really the complete code then cv2 is not defined so you've got bigger problems.

Comment: Looks like synchronous code. So it won't even try to read the keyboard input until the `vid.read()` and other code is done.